# Removing ColumnA from ColumnB, then presenting the results in ColumnC in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with two columns: SetA and SetB.  SetA contains values that must be removed from SetB, so that what I am left with is SetC, which contains ONLY values that are unique to SetB.
Here is a copy of the file I've been beating my head against for the past few hours:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qq8EAPMTrvOiGnIS-cFk2y13KNt7nBahcbflrm-cPmg/edit#gid=0

Note that all my attempts have failed so far because Google Sheets wants to compare based on rows instead of columns.  It looks at A:2, and if doesn't match B:2, it marks the value as "unique", without bothering to see if A:2's value appears elsewhere in B.   **If "12345" is in Row 1 of SetA, and in row 3,456 of SetB, it still needs to be removed from SetB.**

Background: SetA is a list of "good" product codes.  SetB is a list of ALL product codes.  I need to indentify the bad codes, and the only way to do that is to remove the "Good" list from the "Master" list, which will leave me with a "Bad" list.  Thanks in advance!

I tried to compare the data using =UNIQUE(A2:B54341) but all that didn't work, it just echoed the same data.  I was expecting to see a column with only the values from SetB that were NOT in SetA.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit simpler approach.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A,B2:B)=0)))
```

To remove blank rows from ***Column B***.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"",INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A,B2:B)=0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula that finds with BYROW if there is a match in A or not:

```
=FILTER(unique(B2:B),BYROW(UNIQUE(B2:B),LAMBDA(each,IFERROR(MATCH(each,A2:A,0)=0,TRUE))))
```

[image]

Comment: You sir, are my personal hero!  This worked GREAT!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Consider marking the question as answered 